# Torrents on a headless server

Tags: server, headless, torrent-client

I am running a home headless server and I want it to be able to download torrents for each of the home users.

I was looking at Transmission (with its transmission-remote frontend) but I don't like about it that all torrents are downloaded to a common location, since there is no per-user process, just a system-wide daemon.

Which torrent program can let me manage torrents on a headless server without mixing up each user's torrents?

Comment: How about a command line client like aria? Or utorrent?

Comment: You can specify the path to the config file, so you could run multiple daemons on multiple users with their own config file. The only downside is that you'll need a seperate port for each server, but this can be fixed by using a reverse proxy. I don't know if this is possible, it's just an idea.

Comment: Oh well I can manage a separate port for each, no problem. UPNP seems to work with my router. I'm going to test this multiple transmission daemons thing :)

Comment: It seems, however, that transmission-remote will only communicate with the first spawned transmission-daemon :=/